# Is there any way to disable the Touch ID prompt (UIAlertview)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Trying to Integrate TouchId in my application, and i was successful too.

The Question is
Can we customize the Default TouchID UIalertview ?
Can we Disable it?
[image]

Comment: No you can't. Don't think of it as your app displaying that `UIAlertView`/`UIAlertController` think of it as the system is displaying it which you have no control over. So no this isn't possible to change the default touchID `UIAlertView`/`UIAlertController`. And you can definitely no disable it, that is a big no no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot. As Popeye said in a comment, the system controls that prompt, not your app – you simply request that the system display it for you. This is due to obvious security concerns.

For example, what if you initiated a $100 in-app purchase, but changed the prompt to say, "Place your thumb on the home button to start the game!" Clearly that would not go over well.

Comment: Thanks for reply @riley, but how could some of the app show there custom screen instead of Default UIalertviewController/UIalertview

Comment: You can show whatever you want, but if you want to use TouchID, you *must* show the system alert view as-is. You can neither modify nor replace it.

Answer (score 2):

You can customized it the message in the alert can be set with the localizedReason parameter 
`- (void)evaluatePolicy:(LAPolicy)policy localizedReason:(NSString *)localizedReason reply:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSError *error))reply`

You can also set the action button (default is "Enter Password") with

`LAContext *context = [[LAContext alloc] init];
  context.localizedFallbackTitle = [your message]`

The "localizedFallbackTitle" is not in the docs but part of the LAContext .h file