# Codename one: Don't want to display any Dialog by default in FingerprintScanner

Tags: codenameone

I have developed app using Codename one in that I am using FingerprintScanner.cn1 library for Fingerprint functionality.when I calls Fingerprint.scanFingerprint() It scans the finger print and shows the result but at that time default dialog coming with fingerprint icon/image at the begining .I dont want to show that dialog and fingerprint image.What should I do for that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Note the edit to the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dialog is shown by default on iOS except for the new iOS 11 which is still in beta stage.

On Android, the same functionality is simulated by showing a Codename One dialog.

If you want to control Android UI only, you can [fork the FingerprintScanner Source code on GitHub](https://github.com/codenameone/FingerprintScanner) and modify [this class](https://github.com/codenameone/FingerprintScanner/blob/master/src/com/codename1/fingerprint/impl/InternalCallback.java) where the Dialog is shown. Then, clean and build to generate a cn1Lib which you can use in your project.

## Edit:

I've added a method that allows you to specify you don't want to show users a dialog on Android.

To update, right click your project and go to **Codename One -> Codename One Settings -> Extensions**, search for `FingerPrint` and update the extension. If the "Update" is not showing, try again later or you could just download the latest version directly to your **lib folder** from [here](https://github.com/diamondobama/CodenameOneLibs/blob/158f8c0178d06ccde2dc8973f832907e1467247a/cn1libs/FingerprintScanner.cn1lib?raw=true).

Right click your project again and go to **Codename One -> Refresh cn1lib files**

Now change your declaration method to something like this:

```
Fingerprint.scanFingerprint("Use your finger print to unlock AppName.", value -> {
    Log.p("Scan successfull!");
}, (sender, err, errorCode, errorMessage) -> {
    Log.p("Scan Failed!");
}, false); //note the false argument
```

Comment: Thanks,It's working on android but I want to do same thing on IOS .What should I do for that?

Comment: Like I said in my Answer, you can't control that at the moment as it is presented to you by the iOS platform rather than Codename One

Comment: Not that I know of. You could only change the text. Check this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29395854/is-there-any-way-to-disable-the-touch-id-prompt-uialertview